# Не скачивает пакеты npm и файлы с удаленных репозитариев командой git clone

Tags: node.js, git, github, gulp, npm

На рабочем компе не получается скачать что либо с помощью командной строки.

На примере менеджера пакетов npm

Настройки сетевого подключения

[image: Настройки сетевого подключения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Node установлен

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее при попытки закачки или установки какого-либо пакета несколько минут пытается затем
выдает ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке скачать с github несколько минут пытается затем

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал решения сброса proxy все 
Настройки такие

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: `npm` тут вообще ни при чём. Проверяйте настройки вашего файрвола. Или воспользуйтесь другим протоколом (https, ssh)

Comment: `ipconfig /all` и смотрите внимательно...